# How does a website know the Google query I used to find it?

Tags: search-engine

When I search for something such as "`rearrange table columns in asp.net`" on Google, and click the link to [Wrox's forum site](http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-2-0-professional/57221-rearrange-column-order-datatable-dataset.html), the site greets me with a message such as "Your Google search for 'rearrange table columns in asp.net' brought you to Wrox Forum...".

How does a site know what query I typed into Google? And how could I add such an ablity to my site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is parsing your query from the query parameters in the `HTTP_REFERER` server variable, which contains the URL you're coming from and is provided in your HTTP request.

Answer (score 8):

It uses a header known as the "HTTP referrer".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

To use it in your site, you would need some kind of dynamic page generation, such as ASP / ASP.NET, PHP, or Perl.  For example in Perl, you could do something like:

```
if ($ENV{HTTP_REFERER} =~ /google.com\?.+&q=(.+?)&/)
    print "Your google search of $1 brought you to this site";
```

**WARNING**: The code above is only an example and may not be correct or secure!

Answer (score 2):

Like these guys are suggesting, it's the `HTTP_REFERER` header variable. The query is in the "q" key in the URL. So if you want to parse that, you can just sort out the querystring and URL decode the "q" variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks at the referrer header.  Here is some [fairly basic PHP code](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/php_google_referer.php) to do it.